# im Getting driver value=null in inherited class which is inherited from base class and also getting Null point exception(selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

[I have also tried to write that method in base class but here also im getting driver value as null please see the attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dc3m.jpg)
I'm Getting driver value=null in inherited class which is inherited from base class and also getting Null point exception(selenium)

This is the code where I'm facing issue here two classes present one is base class and one is child class

```java
    public class Base
    {
        public WebDriver driver;
        public Properties prop;

        public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {

            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Selenium\\projectsdemo\\src\\main\\java\\data.properties");

            prop.load(fis);
            String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
            System.out.println(browserName);

            if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\Browsersdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                //execute in chrome driver
                return driver;
            }

            //in below class where im inheriting here im getting value of driver=null;

        public class Screenshotusinglistener extends Base {
            public WebDriver driver;
            public void initialize() throws IOException {
                driver = initializeDriver();
                System.out.println("value of driver is" + driver);
            }

            public void Fail() throws Throwable {

                System.out.println("driver=" + driver);
                try {
                    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); //Here getting null pointer may be driver value is null thats why
                    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("d:\\Selenium\\Screenshots\\screenshot.png"));

                    } catch (Exception e) { // TODO: handle exception }
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

the follow line errors:

> File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); //Here getting null pointer may be driver value is null thats why

Comment: Where is your initializeDriver() method?

Comment: @Scruples It's in there - just submitting an edit request to help with code formatting. near the the top you have `public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {`   - seems to be missing a close though

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. Am I blind again or do you never actually return the driver?

Comment: its there just some editing issue but stills im getting value of driver value as null

Comment: What i feel is , your parent and subclass both are having same variable  name driver. So here concept of variable hiding  came into picture. when the child and parent classes both have a variable with the same name, the child class' variable hides the parent class' variable. If you could change the access modifier  or change variable name. That might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Return your driver in base class

```
public class Base {

public WebDriver driver;

public WebDriver initializedriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    return driver;
}

}
```

Comment: its added see the photo of base class   https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dc3m.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Add the following in `Fail()`.

```
public void Fail() throws IOException {
        if (driver == null) {
                initializeDriver();
        }
        //Existing code.
}
```

Check if the `browserName` is equal to `chrome`. The case only in which the `browserName` is `chrome` is handled. That could be the issue too.

```
if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //processing
        return driver;
}
```

Comment: browser is launching and performing task but while taking screenshot im not able to retrive the value of driver which i initilized in base class see another way i tried i write the method in base class itself but issue coming  see the attached photo in this link   https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dc3m.jpg

Comment: i tried another way i write the method in base class itself but issue coming see the attached photo in this link i.stack.imgur.com/3dc3m.jpg

Comment: @beginner Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: I just restarted my eclipse now the null pointer exception is gone but im getting this error ->>>>>>>>driver here is=ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS ()
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id

Comment: @beginner, The purpose of this thread/question is over, You don't see the original issue anymore as per your comments above. For any new issues, do some research by yourself, google about it and in worst case if you don't find any solution, you can create/ask a brand new question. Happy to help.